# How to remove a persistent cookies before Expiration time?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

i have a Wordpress Website, i want to expire my persistent cookies when the user close the browser.
i added the function in functions.php file but it doesn't seem to set for me?

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'expiration_filter_faizan', 99, 3);
function expiration_filter_faizan($seconds, $user_id, $remember){


  if ( $remember ) {

    $expiration = 0;
  } else {

    $expiration = 0;
  }

  if ( PHP_INT_MAX - time() < $expiration ) {
    $expiration =  PHP_INT_MAX - time() - 5;
  }

  return $expiration;
  }
```

Comment: So you only want to remove the cookie?

Comment: no i want alternate solution, like session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using persistent cookies if you want to expire when the browser is closed?

(This is the default behavior for cookies)

Comment: if there is other solution please give me, how can i remove persistent cookies ? and used other like session cookie? what do you suggest?

its wordpress default in: https://stag.maggi.pk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

so please tell me how can i remove this from this file.

Comment: There is no way to delete cookies when the browser is closed from a PHP script on the server since HTTP is stateless.  The server has no idea when the browser window will be closed.  The closest thing to being able to do it would be javascript that would execute during an 'onunload' event of the window, BUT that would fire between page loads.  An IFrame can be used to wrap the site and the javascript attached to the IFrame but that's a bit cumbersome and will likely lead to other, bigger issues.

Comment: If you're attempting to do this due to the EU/UK Cookie Compliancy you'll likely needs something like this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/cookillian/